# Snakemake use file content as shell command

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to automatize a shell command that use the software using snakemake :

```
./chopchop.py -G hg38 -o temp -Target chr16:46390060-46390782
```

In this command the 'chr16:46390060-46390782' input will change.
All different input are in a file in which I'll have to parse to get the appropiate input format

```
cat test.bed 
chr16   46390060    46390782
chr21   33931554    33931728
```

I have a simple snakemake rule that run shell command

```
rule run_chopchop :
    input:
        "/gpfs/home/user/crispr_project/CRISPRi_Enh_TALL/enhancer_dataset/jurkat/test.bed"
    output:
        "/gpfs/home/user/crispr_project/CRISPRi_Enh_TALL/chopchop_output/guide_chopchop.txt"
    shell:'''
    set +u; source /gpfs/home/user/Apps/anaconda3/bin/activate chopchop; set -u
    ./gpfs/home/user/git/chopchop/chopchop.py -G hg38 -o temp -Target {input} > {output}
    '''
```

How can I use the content of the file as input in snakemake and change the syntax of the line to get the appropriate format ? I have really no idea of the syntax. If some can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always replace the `shell:` section with the `run:` one. In this case you need to call the `shell()` function each time you need to run the script:

```py
rule run_chopchop :
    input: "/gpfs/home/user/crispr_project/CRISPRi_Enh_TALL/enhancer_dataset/jurkat/test.bed"
    output: "/gpfs/home/user/crispr_project/CRISPRi_Enh_TALL/chopchop_output/guide_chopchop.txt"
    run:
        # for each line in the file
        input = ...
        output = ...
        shell(f'''
            set +u; source /gpfs/home/user/Apps/anaconda3/bin/activate chopchop; set -u
            ./gpfs/home/user/git/chopchop/chopchop.py -G hg38 -o temp -Target {input} > {output}
        ''')
```